# Will a long filter string affect the search perfomance in ldap?

Tags: c++, openldap

Will a long filter string affect the search perfomance in ldap?

Will it affect the search time?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but this might belong to superuser/serverfault more than here. The reason is that this is programming related only for those that have actually looked at the code and know how the internal data and the query are performed. In superuser/serverfault you might find people with real life experiences with LDAP servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off course it will, simply because its large :)

I would suggest 2 things:

1) Post a example search of what your trying to do in the post, perhaps you definition of large is different from other ppl.
2) Benchmark yourself to see, if the search takes 1 second and thats ok then you have solved your problem.

On a side note, you can direct ldap queries to spesifc domain controlers, so during testing and production perhaps aim it one of the "backup" domain contolers might be a good idea

Comment: I have changed the query and checked there is a huge change in performance.